# Iphone SDK: adding israel roads and streets to MapKit

Tags: iphone, gps, mapkit, geocoding

MKMapview, class of the mapkit framework for the iphone doesn't display israel streets, cities or any other details by default, how can i add it? is there something i have to buy and put in my program? I Just can't find where to start..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudmade was my Map API choice for this case.